# Pandas sort columns seperately

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

```
import pandas as pd

records = [
    {"a": 10, "b": 22},
    {"a": 11, "b": 21},
    {"a": 60, "b": 200},
    {"a": 70, "b": 40},
    {"a": 10, "b": 30},
]

def sort(c):
   # TODO

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)

df.sort_values(["a", "b"], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True, key=sort)

print(df.head())
```

Prints

```
    a    b
4  10   30
0  10   22
1  11   21
2  60  200
3  70   40
```

I want to sort the dataframe by the two columns at the same time - not necessarily respecting data integrity; for example, the result of column `b` should be on the top because of its value, which is 200. `sort_values` will prioritize the columns in the given order but I want to sort each column individually.

I know I can have a custom function for sorting, but which algorithm should I use in this case?

Comment: If you want to prioritize column b then you should sort first by b, and then a. `df.sort_values(['b', 'a'], ascending=[False, True])`

Comment: But I want column a prioritized too

Comment: That's not possible. You first sort by column a, if there are duplicated values, then column b will be sorted accordingly.